# Trigger an Event when value has changed

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, data-binding, user-controls, flash-builder

I'm trying to trigger an event (function) in an air application when a value has changed (i.e. when a user has logged in), but so far I've no succeeded in triggering my function...

I have following code:

A user class:

```
[Bindable]
public class User
{
    private var m_rssLink:String;

    public function get rssLink():String{
        return m_rssLink;
    }

    public function set rssLink(value:String):void{
        m_rssLink = value;
    }
}
```

A header component with id header where the user logs in and the user is defined:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <user:User id="user" />
</fx:Declarations>
```

And finally the mxml code with the actionscript:

```
private var loginWatcher:ChangeWatcher;

protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    this.loginWatcher = ChangeWatcher.watch(header.user, ["rssLink"], sendRequest);
}
```

I've tried to trigger the sendRequest function in a lot of ways by now (with [bindable (event="")], with a bindsetter,... ) and so far Google brought me no other options.

Anyone sees where my code fails, or knows a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have already made a setter property for User. Use that to track user states.

```
public function set rssLink(value:String):void{
    if (m_rsslink==value) return;
    m_rssLink = value;
    dispatchEvent(...); // use correct event(s) for certain values, then catch 
    // them in your watcher class. Use FlexEvents if you want.
}
```